# Not possible to pass jmeter variable to sql query in JDBC Request

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

In Jmeter, I have fetched data using 'CSV data set config. Now I got stuck how these data can be passed to Mysql database using JDBC request.  I have added a query
'INSERT INTO rawdata_bk (data) VALUES ($data)'. But I am getting error like "Unknown column '$data' in 'field list'" So my question is how can i Pass the data from csv file to database row by row

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) have slightly different syntax, you need to refer them as:

- `${data}` - direct reference
- `${__V(data)}` - via [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)

Full query will look like: `INSERT INTO rawdata_bk (data) VALUES (${data})`

If you will need to check `${data}` variable value it can be done via [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination, see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for details.

Comment: I got reponse like "Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list'"                   //xxx is the data fetched from csv datasheet. My table name is  rawdata_bk and coloumn headres are data and ID

Comment: This is rather SQL question than JMeter one, blind shot - surround this `{data}` with quotation marks like `'${data}'` in case of varchar  data type or derivatives

Comment: how can we sort out this issue?

Comment: 1. Create a MySQL query in MySQL command-line client or any other MySQL client tool and verify that it works. 2. Use this query in JMeter as is and verify that it works.  3. Substitute hard-coded value with the variable from CSV file.